# Java - Getting a more specific type than "Class<?>" for a parameterized generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a base interface that is parameterized using a type `R` extending the same base interface :

```
public interface IWidget<R extends IWidget<R>> {}
```

Then another interface is parameterized the same way :

```
public interface IWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>> {}
```

Finally, a class implements the second interface. This class will receive the `IWidget` *implementation* class when it will be declared :

```
public class MyWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>> implements IWidgetManager<R> {}
```

**My question :**

What is *the more specific type* that we can use to specify `MyWidgetManager`?

`Class<?>` works, of course :

```
public Class<?> ok() {
    return MyWidgetManager.class;
}
```

But it is very generic and I'd like something more specific...

Those attempts don't compile:

---

```
public Class<? extends IWidgetManager<?>> fails() {
    return MyWidgetManager.class;
}
```

==> *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MyWidgetManager> to Class<? extends IWidgetManager<?>>*

---

```
public <R extends IWidget<?>> Class<? extends IWidgetManager<R>> fails() {
    return MyWidgetManager.class;
}
```

==> *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MyWidgetManager> to Class<? extends IWidgetManager<R>>*

---

```
public <R extends IWidget<R>> Class<? extends IWidgetManager<R>> fails() {
    return MyWidgetManager.class;
}
```

==> *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MyWidgetManager> to Class<? extends IWidgetManager<R>>*

---

```
public Class<? extends IWidgetManager<? extends IWidget<?>>> fails() {
    return MyWidgetManager.class;
}
```

==> *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MyWidgetManager> to Class<? extends IWidgetManager<? extends IWidget<?>>>*

---

Is there any way I can get a type more specific than `Class<?>` for `MyWidgetManager.class`?

**UPDATE :**
I changed the name of my interfaces. The final class is *not* a Widget itself, which wasn't clear in my original question... Sorry for the confusion.

**UPDATE 2 :**

Things are way easier when using concrete types, indeed.

This is really specific to my current situation, but I think I'll fix my "problem" by transforming `MyWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>> implements IWidgetManager<R>` into a `WidgetManagerBase` that doesn't implement anything. Then provide a default implementation with a concrete Widget class. Finally, the get method could be overriden easily (which is my main goal from the start, by the way!). So :

```
public interface IWidget<R extends IWidget<?>> {}
public interface IWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>> {}
public class WidgetManagerBase {}

// Default implementation
public class WidgetA implements IWidget<WidgetA> {}
public class AWidgetManager extends WidgetManagerBase implements IWidgetManager<WidgetA> {}

// default get method
public Class<? extends IWidgetManager<?>> getWidgetManagerClass() {
    return AWidgetManager.class;
}
```

// The default get method then can be overriden with :

```
public class WidgetB implements IWidget<WidgetB> {}
public class BWidgetManager extends WidgetManagerBase implements IWidgetManager<WidgetB> {}

@Override
public Class<? extends IWidgetManager<?>> getWidgetManagerClass() {
    return BWidgetManager.class;
}
```

Comment: Why not `public interface IBaseWidget<R extends IBaseWidget<R>> {}`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Good point, done! Thanks.

Comment: Do you even need a more specific type than `Class<?>`? Apart from getting `Constructor<T>` objects and maybe enum constants (in case of enum types) in a type-safe manner, it's not much you can do with a more specific `Class<...>` type. It will only complicate your interfaces. I'd recommend to stick with `Class<?>` unless it's really necessary.

Comment: @Nándor Előd Fekete The thing is this is a method that can be overriden. I want to be as specifc as possible as its return type to help as much as possible the child class implementor.

Comment: Before using a recursive generic type definition, be sure that you really want it.  If it is required only that the type parameter be a subclass of `IWidget`, then you'll save yourself a number of type matching headaches by using `IWidget<R extends IWidget<?>>` (which still retains type safety).  Use the type recursion only if you really must have it.

Comment: @scottb Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [Java Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the most specific match for `MyWidget.class` is `Class<? extends IWidget>`:

```
public Class<? extends IWidget> test() {
    return MyWidget.class;
}
```

If you want to be even more specific than you should extend MyWidget with concrete type parameters:

```
public class ConcreteBaseWidget implements IBaseWidget<ConcreteBaseWidget> {
}

public class ConcreteWidget extends MyWidget<ConcreteBaseWidget> {
}
```

And then all these methods will work:

```
public Class<? extends IWidget<? extends IBaseWidget<? extends IBaseWidget<?>>>> test1() {
    return ConcreteWidget.class;
}

public Class<? extends IWidget<? extends IBaseWidget<ConcreteBaseWidget>>> test2() {
    return ConcreteWidget.class;
}

public Class<? extends IWidget<? extends ConcreteBaseWidget>> test3() {
    return ConcreteWidget.class;
}
```

Comment: I do not have the concret type in advance, that's the point. But `public Class<? extends IWidget> test()` works indeed with a `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I really think you're just looking for

```
public interface IBaseWidget<R extends IBaseWidget<R>> {}
```

and

```
public interface IWidget<R extends IWidget<R>> extends IBaseWidget<R> {} //not sure about this one.
```

and

```
public class MyWidget implements IWidget<MyWidget> {}
```

That way you can see `MyWidget.class` as `Class<R>`.

Is this what you are looking for, or do I misinterpret your intentions?

**EDIT:**

In that case,

```
public interface IWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>> {}

public class MyWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>> implements IWidgetManager<R> {}
```

could be replaced with

```
public interface IWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>, WM extends IWidgetManager<R, WM>> {}

public class MyWidgetManager<R extends IWidget<R>> implements IWidgetManager<R, MyWidgetManager> {}
```

because then you **will** be able to access `MyWidgetManager.class` as `Class<WM>`.

Comment: I modified the names of the interfaces because my question wasn't clear enough... The last interface (which was name `MyWidget`) is not a widget itself! I rename it `IWidgetManager`. Still, my question remains...

Comment: About your edit : `WM extends IWidgetManager<WM>` doesn't work because `IWidgetManager` has two parameters.

Comment: Right, I mixed that up but now I've fixed it

Comment: Missing a `<B>` on the last occurence of `MyWidgetManager` but indeed after I can see it as `Class<MyWidgetManager>` and `Class<? extends IWidgetManager> `. But I don't want to use the concrete type.. Thanks for your help.